# Output caching on PartialViews doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

OutputCaching on the main controller actions seems to work fine but for PartialViews they don't seem to work as expected.

I added the attribute in one of the partialviews, debugged it. I continuously hit the breakpoint inside the method (which i think means output caching isn't working).  I tried providing parameters, cacheprofiles, enablingoutputcaching and fragments but same effect.  Is there something else that I am missing?

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
        [OutputCache(Duration = 60000, VaryByParam = "componentId;")]
        public PartialViewResult NewCategoryComboPartial(string componentId)
        {
            //ComponentId
            ViewData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.ComponentId.ToString()] = componentId;

            //ViewModel
            ViewData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.ProfileComponentCategories.ToString()] = GetComponentCategoriesList();

            return PartialView("~/Views/Compliance/Profile/Partials/NewCategoryCombo.ascx");
        }
```

Is it because of an existing action filter?  ValidateInputAttribute?  My PartialView()?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the code snippet from the main view on how the partialview is declared.

```
        <div id="compliance-navigation-control">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Compliance/ComplianceNavigationControl.ascx", Model.PandCRecord); %>
        </div>
```

Below is the content of the partialview

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="atp.webnav.Web.Controllers" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="atp.webnav.Web.Utilities" %>

<% Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(x =>
        {
            x.Name = "categoryComboBox_" + ViewData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.ComponentId.ToString()].ToString();  
            x.Theme = "Glass";
            x.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            x.Properties.ValueType = typeof(string);
            x.Properties.TextField = "Name";
            x.Properties.ValueField = "Id";
            x.SelectedIndex = 0;
            x.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
            x.Properties.MaxLength = 30;
            x.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
            x.Properties.AllowUserInput = true;
            x.CallbackRouteValues = new {Controller = "Profile", Action = "NewCategoryComboPartial"};
            x.Properties.EnableCallbackMode = true;
            x.Properties.CallbackPageSize = 1000;
            x.Properties.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "webnav.compliance.profile.categoryComboBox_OnBeginCallback";
            x.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "webnav.compliance.profile.categoryComboBox_OnSelectedIndexChanged"; 
            x.Properties.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "webnav.compliance.profile.categoryComboBox_OnSelectedIndexChanged"; 
            x.Properties.ClientSideEvents.CallbackError = DevExpressGridViewHelper.HandleCallbackErrors;

            x.Properties.EnableSynchronizationOnPerformCallback = true;
        })
        .BindList(ViewData[ControllerEnums.GlobalViewDataProperty.ProfileComponentCategories.ToString()])
        .Render();     
%>
```

Essentially this combobox is a devexpress combobox that has autocomplete features.  It uses callbacks to the controller actions to get the data based on the value selected.  I am trying to see if I can cache the results of the callback.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but you may need to get rid of the semicolon after componentId in VaryByParam

Comment: Agreed - i think that's it. Output caching on PartialViews **does** work (i used it all over the place). And yes @llapinski's points are valid too.

Comment: bwisitero says he put break points, which were hit, so I guess my response might not be valid. Just a guess - maybe you call action method directly from page, for instance you use T4MVC, and Action method with parameter ActionResult and did not regenerate templates?

Answer (score 2):

How are you calling it? Using `Html.Partial` or `Html.Action` (as a child action)?

Quoting from [Donut Hole Caching in ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx)

"the Html.RenderPartial method ignores any OutputCache directives on the view user control"
so use Html.Action/Html.RenderAction. As they say here [Caching ChildActions using cache profiles won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728958/caching-childactions-using-cache-profiles-wont-work) use parameters Duraction and optionally VaryByParam. Profile wont work.

Comment: I am calling it using RenderPartial.  I will edit my posting to include the calling page to make it clearer.